Change SwiftData ModelContainer from a class to another and migration
I'm trying to change my model container class on a Movie application.
Actually I've this :
var sharedModelContainer: ModelContainer = {
    let schema = Schema([
        LocalMovie.self,
    ])
    let modelConfiguration = ModelConfiguration(schema: schema, isStoredInMemoryOnly: false)

    do {
        return try ModelContainer(for: schema, configurations: [modelConfiguration])
    } catch {
        fatalError("Could not create ModelContainer: \(error)")
    }
}()

with this @Model :
@Model
class LocalMovie: Codable, Hashable {
   var id: Int
   var title: String
   var posterPath: String
   var overview: String
   var minAge: Int
   var seen: Bool
   var priority: Priority

   static func == (lhs: LocalMovie, rhs: LocalMovie) -> Bool {
    return lhs.id == rhs.id
   }

   func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
    hasher.combine(id)
   }

   init(id: Int, title: String, posterPath: String, overview: String, minAge: Int, seen: Bool, priority: Priority) {
    self.id = id
    self.title = title
    self.posterPath = posterPath
    self.overview = overview
    self.minAge = minAge
    self.seen = seen
    self.priority = priority
   }

   required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    id = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .id)
    title = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .title)
    posterPath = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .posterPath)
    overview = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .overview)
    minAge = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .minAge)
    seen = try container.decode(Bool.self, forKey: .seen)
    priority = try container.decode(Priority.self, forKey: .priority)
   }

   func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
    var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    try container.encode(id, forKey: .id)
    try container.encode(title, forKey: .title)
    try container.encode(posterPath, forKey: .posterPath)
    try container.encode(overview, forKey: .overview)
    try container.encode(minAge, forKey: .minAge)
    try container.encode(seen, forKey: .seen)
    try container.encode(priority, forKey: .priority)
   }

   enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case id
    case title
    case posterPath = "poster_path"
    case overview
    case minAge
    case seen
    case priority
   }

That's work great. But I want to move this into an another model, with invisible migration for the user. Actual @Model need to go into the movies of my new @Model. My new @Model is :
@Model
class Child: Codable, Hashable {
var id: Int
var name: String
var birthdate: String
var movies: [LocalMovie]

static func == (lhs: Child, rhs: Child) -> Bool {
    return lhs.id == rhs.id
}

func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
    hasher.combine(id)
}

init(id: Int, name: String, birthdate: String, movies: [LocalMovie]) {
    self.id = id
    self.name = name
    self.birthdate = birthdate
    self.movies = movies
}

required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    id = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .id)
    name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
    birthdate = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .birthdate)
    movies = try container.decode([LocalMovie].self, forKey: .movies)
}

func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
    var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    try container.encode(id, forKey: .id)
    try container.encode(name, forKey: .name)
    try container.encode(birthdate, forKey: .birthdate)
    try container.encode(movies, forKey: .movies)
}

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case id
    case name
    case birthdate
    case movies
}

}
Did you have any suggestions ? Cause I didn't found yet ...

It’s unclear what your question is but you need to do a migration

Actually I've a ModelContainer with [LocalMovie.self] and I want to migrate to [Child.self] and transfer actual data into the movies variable of new one.
We can migrate with different Model Class ?

Yes I believe so, you need some custom migration code of course.
